# LWUIT Painter : How to draw a line on top of a Image Label?

Tags: java, java-me, label, lwuit

I have an image label created like this.

```
Painter painter = new Painter() 
        {

            public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rctngl) 
            {
                g.setColor(0x000000);
                g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
            }
        };
        mapScreen = new Form("Map");
        try 
        {
            Image image = Image.createImage("/res/Sample.jpg");
            Label labelImage = new Label(image);
            labelImage.setScrollVisible(true);
            labelImage.setFocus(true);
            labelImage.getStyle().setBgPainter(painter);
            mapScreen.addComponent(labelImage);
```

I want to draw some lines on top of it. I have tried using painter like the code above but I was not able to do it successfully. How am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

The drawing of the lines is successful but the problem is that the lines are drawn behind the labelImage. How can I make it so that the lines will be drawn infront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the painter to Unselected and Selected style since you give the label focus. You are also drawing a diagonal line not a strait line.

Comment: I have tried using the unselected and selected style, but still I am not able to draw the line.

Comment: I have found the problem. The line has been drawn at the back of the labelImage. So how can I draw the line in from of the labelImage?

Comment: A painter always draws behind the component by definition. You can derive the component and override paint() to draw on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

What about deriving the `Label` class and implementing the `paint(Graphics g)` method ! There you can use the `Graphics` object 'g' to `draw` the `line` and the `image`.

Comment: I think that will work but I am not sure how to derive the Label class and how to use the object 'g'.

I have tried creating custom label but I am not able to make it work, it only paints the image but not the lines.